# How to test iOS applications for iOS v 3.1 compatibility with Xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode4.2, ios3.0

I have Xcode Version 4.2 ,Build 4D199. I need to test an application for iOS 3.1 compatibility. How to load iOS 3.1 simulator?

I also have iPhone 2 with os 3.1.3 (7E18). I set the deployment target has 3.1 and added armv6 in architecture section of both target and project build settings. When I use this device for debugging, build will be successful, but application wont run.
What are the proper project settings to use iOS device v 3.1.3 in Xcode 4.2 for development?

Comment: When saying the App won't run, what exactly is the output on the console? Do you get any exceptions or other debugging invocations?

Comment: There will be no exceptions. It says "build succeeded" and then status changes to "finished running ...on iPhone..".

Comment: @user1017099 That's in the xcode status bar, what about in the console application? There should be more detail there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your iPhone 2 device properly provisioned for development? You won't be allowed to run it on that device unless you've added the device in the provisioning portal and that device has been added to your development certificate.